# How to speed up jq expression?

Tags: jq

I use the following jq code to extract data from a json file. I am sure that there is at most one object with "/Type".N being "/Catalog". How can I instruct jq to stop once it sees the first object with "/Type".N being "/Catalog"?

```
.[] | select(.[1] | objects."/Type".N == "/Catalog") | .[1]."/Dests"
```

EDIT: I tried the following commands. Neither of them speed up much. As it is know the match is at the end of the file, supposedly, a tool that can look up at the end of a file should finish the search very quickly. Does jq always take input as a stream? If so, there is no way to get the result very quickly?

- `.[][1] | select(objects."/Type".N == "/Catalog")."/Dests"`

```
real    0m8.905s
user    0m8.063s
sys 0m0.822s
```

- `first(reverse[][1] | select(objects."/Type".N == "/Catalog")."/Dests")`

```
real    0m9.228s
user    0m8.315s
sys 0m0.875s
```

Comment: What do you mean by "end of the file" exactly? If the file contains a JSON array, is the item of interest in the very last item, for example?

Comment: @peak Yes. The last item contains the match.

Answer (score 1):

Use `first/1`.

From the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#first%28expr%29%2Clast%28expr%29%2Cnth%28n%3Bexpr%29) on `first/1`:

> The `first(expr)` and `last(expr)` functions extract the first and last values from `expr`, respectively.

```bash
first(.[] | select(.[1] | objects."/Type".N == "/Catalog") | .[1]."/Dests")
```

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L177), `first/1` is defined using `break` to stop at the first match:

```bash
def first(g): label $out | g | ., break $out;
```

Comment: I just notice that the matching element is at the end of the input json. So `first` does not help the speed. In this case, what is the best way to let jq look at the end of the file to quickly find the match then return?

Comment: @user119720 You could try to `reverse` the array, i.e. `first(reverse[] | select…)`

Comment: Note: If in both, the `select` filter and the output. you only care about `.[1]`, you could iterate over just that by bringing it up front: `first(.[][1] | select(objects."/Type".N == "/Catalog")."/Dests")` (or with using `reverse`: `first(reverse[][1] | select(objects."/Type".N == "/Catalog")."/Dests")`)

Comment: They do speed up much. See my edit of the question.

Comment: @user119720 - Your original question and your new question have very little to do with each other.  It would probably be best if you accepted the answer by pmf here, and then asked a separate question, being careful to give a tiny but illustrative example in accordance with the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: I can't. SO has a very stupid 90 minutes rule.

Comment: You can; you just have to wait 90 minutes. It's not that hard.

Answer (score 1):

To access the very last item in a JSON array without the overhead of parsing the entire array is beyond jq's current capabilities.  (jq's `--stream` option is economical with memory, but is snail-paced.)

One family of possible alternatives would be to use a tool that will "splat" the array efficiently for you (i.e. produce a stream of the top-level items), with one item per line), and then use `tail` (or equivalent) and finally jq.

Some tools for splatting are my own [`jm` and `jm.py`](https://www.github.com/pkoppstein/jm) (based on PHP and Python respectively), [jj](https://github.com/tidwall/jj), and [jstream](https://github.com/bcicen/jstream).  For jj, you would write:

```
jj -l '@this'
```

jj in this context is a bit of a memory hog but in my experience quite fast; jm, jm.py and jstream are fast and economical with memory.

As one example:

```
jm input.json | last -n 1 | jq ...
```

Please feel free to share your timing results in the comments.